# Bitcoin 0.17 No public key shown (validateaddress)

Tags: bitcoind, multi-signature

I want to generate multisignature address with person, which I didn't know.

Someone send me a public key. Then I do:

```
bitcoin-cli getnewaddress "" legacy
```

Ok, I got

```
1QKVwuQnu69HgsMVvynFhApYmmdLf8bMKT
```

After that, I need to know my own public key:

```
bitcoin-cli validateaddress "1QKVwuQnu69HgsMVvynFhApYmmdLf8bMKT"
```

But v.017 do not give me a public key:

```
{
"isvalid": true,
"address": "1QKVwuQnu69HgsMVvynFhApYmmdLf8bMKT",
  "scriptPubKey": "76a914ffca8b339408c5eb664513f62c98256c5edcc98b88ac",
  "isscript": false,
  "iswitness": false
}
```

Is there any way to generate multisignature address (2 of 2) if wallet do not know one of this addressess ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`validateaddress` has changed to be separate from the wallet, so it cannot look up the public key information for an address. Use `getaddressinfo` instead in order to get all of the wallet information for an address, including the public key.